# Prove that {$f_n$ + $g_n$} converges pointwise to $f+g$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convergence-divergence

Let $I$ be any interval. Suppose that {$f_n$} converges pointwise to $f$ on $I$ and that {$g_n$} converges pointwise to $g$ on $I$.

Prove that {$f_n$ + $g_n$} converges pointwise to $f+g$.

I am having difficulty proving this without assuming uniform convergence.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Well, which proof would you give if you had uniform convergence? -- You only need to know that the sum of convergent sequences is a convergent sequence for this.

Comment: yes but how would you thoroughly prove this?

Comment: by writing down the definitions and verifiying they apply.

Answer (score 2):

Fix $x\in I$. We will show $f_{n}(x)+g_{n}(x)\to f(x)+g(x)$ as $n\to\infty$. For a given $\epsilon>0$, there exist positive integers $N_{1},N_{2}$ such that $|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon/2$ for $n\geq N_{1}$ and $|g_{n}(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon/2$ for $n\geq N_{2}$. Let $N=\max\{N_{1},N_{2}\}$ and suppose $n\geq N$ Then, you should be able to use the triangle inequality to conclude that $|f_{n}(x)+g_{n}(x)-f(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon$ for $n\geq N$.

You are trying to prove pointwise convergence, not uniform convergence, so proving convergence at each $x$ suffices.